# Pyspark jdbc in docker

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark/jupyter notebook docker container to run my spark job. I need to connect to my postgresql in localhost. I'm getting connection refused error. I s there any way to  connect to database in localhost. I have also tried changing the connection url to host.docker.internal instead of localhost

I need to connect my pyspark/jupyter notebook in the docker with the postgresql in the local.

Comment: do you know where are your workers ? Is the connection between your workers and the local postgre open ?

Comment: Thanks much for your comment Steven. Yes, I think so. Let me know how to find it. I'm using linux (ubuntu), I have stopped all the fire walls. But, could not connect. I'm getting java connection refused exception and if by adding the extra host i get no route to host exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. You basically need to create your own Dockerfile and add JDBC jar file into the path where PySpark would read it from.

https://towardsdatascience.com/tutorial-running-pyspark-inside-docker-containers-84970d12b20e

Here is a hint on how to build such Dockerfile.